# Unable to get data from the List to build the ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from the jsonplaceholder todos API, Once I retrieve the data I'm storing it into a List and notifying all the listeners. But something weird is happening.

```
class Todos with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Todo> _items = [];

  List<Todo> get item {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future fetchAndSetData() async {
    try {
      const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
      final List<dynamic> response =
          json.decode((await http.get(Uri.parse(url))).body);

      List<Todo> extractedTodo =
          response.map((dynamic item) => Todo.fromJson(item)).toList();

      _items = extractedTodo;
      print(_items.length); // Getting 200 which is exact length I'm expecting

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is where I'm making a get request and storing the data into the List. The following code is where I'm calling the fetchAndSetData with the help of Provider.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    Provider.of<Todos>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetData().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : TodoList(),
    );
  }
}
```

The following is where I'm trying to get the todos from the items list.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todos = Provider.of<Todos>(context, listen: false).item;
    print(todos.length);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: todos.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(todos[index].title),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Once didChangeDependencies, it will call the fetchAndSetData and will set the List, so the print statement on the Todos class will print 200 as the length of items I'm expecting but in the TodoList class where I'm calling the getter, the length I'm receiving is 0.

Now the weird part is when I removed the `listen: false` in the didChangeDependencies, the print statement on the fetchAndSetData getting called again and again. With that I mean the length for the todos is 200 but the print goes beyond 200. As, there is no way that the data gets updated, so I mark those as `listen: false`

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please fetch your data in

```
Future<List<dynamic>> _post;

 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _post = fetchAndSetData();
  }
```

and then use a FutureBuilder like this

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: _post,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But the requirement is to make it work using the Provider package.

Comment: ok then just move your didChangeDependencies logic to initState method

Comment: There, the context won't be available.

Comment: You can use the GetX Package for state management. It does not depend on context.

You will love it once you try it: https://pub.dev/packages/get